# Why Won't This Vuejs "Hello World" Example Render On My Computer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I'm trying to use Vue with a Phoenix/Elixir project. After a great deal of troubleshooting I still could not get Vuejs elements to render.  So I decided to test the simple "hello world" example in raw html/js.

It won't work either.  What am I doing wrong?

Here's the jsfiddle I'm trying to duplicate on my computer:
https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/okv0rgrk/

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Vue Test</title>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  }
})
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="app">
    {{ message }}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to add your scripts in the head of your html file. Or wrap it inside a `window.onload` hook

Comment: If you inspect the iframe generated by that fiddle, you'll see that the code in the `javascript` panel, is inserted in the head of the iframe

Comment: I believe the scripts are in the head tag?

Comment: haha you are right, my bad. But check the generated iframe in the fiddle you posted, the Vue instance is wrapped in a window.onload event. Try that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your second `script` tag before `</body>`. The reason your code isn't working is because you're trying to mount `#app` before it exists. If you try to mount it after it's there it'll be fine.

Comment: As @Bill mentioned, your second script tag needs to occur after the `#app` div.  In practice, you should include all of your script tags as the last items in the html body.

Comment: Unless the OP has edited his question from original, the second script IS before the `</body>`. So I am unsure what you mean

Comment: Immediately before `</body>`. Not just before it from a line number perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a minimal example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <p>{{ message }}</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Must put the script below after the app div -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
        }
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```